# sending array of sbytes through socket in client-server architecture C#

Tags: c#

I would like to send array of sbytes. a[2] and a[3] are numbers -100..100.

```
static void speed_control(Socket sock)
    {         
        sbyte[] a = new sbyte[5];

        a[0] = Convert.ToSByte('[');
        a[1] = Convert.ToSByte(14);     
        a[2] = Convert.ToSByte(Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine()));
        a[3] = Convert.ToSByte(Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine()));
        a[4] = Convert.ToSByte(']');

        sock.Send(a);
    }
```

sock.Send(a) gives me this error: cannot convert from sbyte[] to byte[].

Is there any other simple way to send this kind of data?

Comment: why are you wanting a `sbyte` here?

Comment: Use `byte` instead of `sbyte`.

Comment: You need to realize that you're sending a binary representation.  Do you know how signed numbers work in binary?

Comment: so if i want to send -100, i will have to send this sock.Send(228)?

Comment: Yes, though I prefer to use `Convert.ToByte(100)`, then set the left-most bit to 1 using a binary-or:  `n = (byte)(n | 0x80);`.

Comment: well, works fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets send and receive data in binary representation.

Your -100...100 numbers are not the binary representation, they are the data themselves. So typically, you need to convert your numbers to binary and then send them.

If you don't want to use the standard way and really insist in sending doing it your way, then you can do this:

Numbers between 0 and 100 can be sent as is. Number between -1 and -100, can be converted to numbers between 101 and 200 and then sent. The other side must reverse the calculation. So you'll be using `byte`, but not as binary data.

However, in that case your example doesn't make any sense. You seem to be sending characters, so you will never get negative values, and you must use the standard way and just change:

```
sbyte[] a = new sbyte[5];
```

to:

```
byte[] a = new byte[5];
```

If that example doesn't really represent what you're actually doing, then please update your question and post a better example that clearly shows how you are getting numbers -100...100.

Answer (score 0):

If `Socket.Send` wants `byte[]` you have to provide `byte[]`

```
 static void speed_control(Socket sock) {
   unchecked { // we don't want IntegerOverflow to be thrown on (byte) -100 and alike
     sock.Send(new byte[] {
       (byte) '[',
        14, 
       (byte) Convert.ToSByte(Console.ReadLine()), 
       (byte) Convert.ToSByte(Console.ReadLine()), 
       (byte) ']'  
     });
   } 
 }
```

Even if the actual range is `-100..100` you can use `byte`, not `sbyte` if you just *cast*

```
sbyte s =
byte  b = unchecked((byte)s);

...

sbyte s = unchecked((sbyte)b);
```

and let the system use [binary complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

```
-100 (sbyte) ~ 156 (byte)
 -99         ~ 157 
 ...
  -1         ~ 255
```